# OpenLayers maps inside Twitter Bootstrap subtabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, openlayers

I've some problems in correctly center an OpenLayers-2.13 map inside a Twitter Bootstrap-2.3.2 layout.
I've got a layout constituted by 2 tabs, and each one of them has 3 subtabs.
The first of every subtab contains my map:

```
<ul id="shape-tabs-links" class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="pill" class="shapetab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2" data-toggle="pill" class="shapetab">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="shape-tabs" class="tab-content">

    <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-pane" value="1">
        <ul id="per-shape-tabs-links-1" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li><a href="#tabs-view-1" data-toggle="tab" class="subtab">Subtab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-cods-1" data-toggle="tab" class="subtab">Subtab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-info-1" data-toggle="tab" class="subtab">Subtab 3</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="per-shape-tabs-1" class="tab-content">
            <div id="tabs-view-1" class="tab-pane">
                <!-- Subtab 1 -->
                <div id="view-map-1" class="map" style="width:100%;height:512px;">
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-cods-1" class="tab-pane"><!-- Subtab 2 --></div>
            <div id="tabs-info-1" class="tab-pane"><!-- Subtab 3 --></div>
        </div><!-- per-shape-tabs-1 -->
    </div><!-- tabs-1 -->

    <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-pane" value="2">
        <ul id="per-shape-tabs-links-2" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li><a href="#tabs-view-2" data-toggle="tab" class="subtab">Subtab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-cods-2" data-toggle="tab" class="subtab">Subtab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-info-2" data-toggle="tab" class="subtab">Subtab 3</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="per-shape-tabs-2" class="tab-content">
            <div id="tabs-view-2" class="tab-pane">
                <!-- Subtab 1 -->
                <div id="view-map-2" class="map" style="width:100%;height:512px;">
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-cods-2" class="tab-pane"><!-- Subtab 2 --></div>
            <div id="tabs-info-2" class="tab-pane"><!-- Subtab 3 --></div>
        </div><!-- per-shape-tabs-2 -->
    </div><!-- tabs-2 -->

</div><!-- shape-tabs -->
```

To show my map I use a JQuery function on document loading:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shape-tabs-links a:first').tab('show');       // Tab 1
    $('#per-shape-tabs-links-1 a:first').tab('show'); // Subtab 1
    renderMaps([1,2]); // Where I create my map...
});
```

If I load my page, my map inside tab-1/subtab-1 is perfectly centered and visible.
But If I move to the second tab, I have my second map (tab-2/subtab-1) shifted to left, as depicted in this picture:
[image]
The strange thing to me is that If I resize my browser window, my map in tab-2/subtab1 get automagically centered!
I think that the problem comes from the Bootstrap `show` property, because if I modify my onload function like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shape-tabs-links a:last').tab('show');        // Tab 2
    $('#per-shape-tabs-links-2 a:first').tab('show'); // Subtab 1
    renderMaps([1,2]); // Where I create my map...
});
```

I correctly visualize the second map, but the first one gets shifted to the left.
Is there a way to correct this behaviour?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the page

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/bootstrap.html

on how to use bootstrap with openlayers

Comment: Yes, but it did'n help. The solution is reported in [this other question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63675/openlayers-dynamic-map-width-inside-bootstrap-tabs).